# Ввод и вывод изображения с помощью приложения на C#

Tags: c#

Имеется "приложение" для внесения сведений в базу данных и с последующим его извлечением. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

со следующим кодом:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet1.items' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.itemsTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet1.items);

        }

        private void serviseLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = nameTextBox.Text;
            string servise = serviseTextBox.Text;
            string photo = photoPictureBox.ImageLocation;
            this.database1DataSet1.items.Rows.Add(name, servise, photo);
            this.itemsTableAdapter.Update(this.database1DataSet1.items);
        }

        private void photoPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            photoPictureBox.ImageLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            this.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }

        private void serviseTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

в итоге при внесении сведений появляется вот такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понял тип данных не подходит, на какой тогда его нужно изменить.

Comment: Вам же пишут,  что ожидают тип `byte[]`.

Comment: А где этот тип прописать??

Comment: Попробуйте что-то типа: `var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(photo); this.database1DataSet1.items.Rows.Add(name, servise, bytes);`

Comment: @user263350 пользователь Андрей написал вам правильно. В вашем dataSet'e колонка photo является массивом байт, т.е. там должна содержаться сама картинка, а не путь до файла с картинкой.